# Python Plotly - restyle pie with buttons

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, plotly, plotly-python

I'm trying to restyle a plotly pie (labels, marker, values), configured via python django. But I'm unable to do it properly - the values are not taken by the pie.
I expect to update the pie by new values (do not be suprised: the example below has equal values), new colors and labels in the legend. But it behaves like the pie does not change or values are not set properly.

I already had a look into the live generated javascript code and compared it to the examples delivered by plotly but i have not seen any differences. My code is currently:

```
layout = go.Layout(
    paper_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
    plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
    font_color="white",
    legend=dict(
        orientation="v",
        yanchor="bottom",
        y=0.05,
        xanchor="left",
        x=1.05,
        traceorder='reversed'
    ),
    height=300,
    margin=dict(l=2, r=2, t=1, b=1),
)
```

...

```
fig = go.Figure(go.Pie(labels=['Automatic', 'Error'], values=[13,11],
                       marker=dict(colors=['#000000','#555555']), sort=False),  layout)
fig.update_traces(textposition='inside',textinfo='value')
fig.update_layout(uniformtext_minsize=12, uniformtext_mode='hide')
button_layer_1_height = 1.08
fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        dict(
            buttons=list([
                 dict(
                     args=[
                        {'labels': ['test1', 'test2']},
                        {'marker': dict(colors=['#999999', '#222222'])},
                        {'values': [23,1]}
                     ],
                     label='firstButton',
                     method="restyle"
                 ),
                 dict(
                     args=[
                        {'labels': ['test3', 'test4']},
                        {'marker': dict(colors=['#333333', '#666666'])},
                        {'values': [10,14]}
                     ],
                     label='SecondButton',
                     method="restyle",
                 ),
             ]),
            direction="down",
            pad={"r": 10, "t": 10},
            showactive=True,
            x=0.1,
            xanchor="left",
            y=button_layer_1_height,
            yanchor="top",
        ),
    ]
)
```

which leads into javascript:

```
"updatemenus":[{"buttons":[
{"args":[{"labels":["test1", "test2"]},{"marker":{"colors":["#999999", "#222222"]}},{"values":[23,1]}}],"label":"FirstButton","method":"restyle"},
{"args":[{"labels":["test3", "test4"]},{"marker":{"colors":["#333333", "#666666"]}},{"values":[10,14]}}],"label":"SecondButton","method":"restyle"}],
"direction":"down","pad":{"r":10,"t":10},"showactive":true,"x":0.1,"xanchor":"left","y":1.08,"yanchor":"top"}]},                        {"responsive": true}                    )                };
```

Rendered Properly at initial call of the Pie:[inital rendering, before button click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCfUN.png)

But after clicking the button, it is not updated (values and color of pie not changed, labels are set to '0' and '1'):
[After Button click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7P5r.png)

**Solution**

Buttons were wrong (forgot square brackets, args in one bracket):

```
buttons=list([
                 dict(
                     args=[
                        {'labels': ]['test1', 'test2']],
                        'marker': dict(colors=]['#999999', '#222222']]),
                        'values': ][23,1]]}
                     ],
                     label='firstButton',
                     method="restyle"
                 ),
                 dict(
                     args=[
                        {'labels': [['test3', 'test4']],
                        'marker': dict(colors=[['#333333', '#666666']]),
                        'values': [[10,14]]}
                     ],
                     label='SecondButton',
                     method="restyle",
                 ),
             ]),
```

Comment: Your question isn't reproducible, so it's pretty much impossible to provide an absolute answer. However, I'm going to guess that your original pie graph has more than one value. However, it looks like your buttons only have one element for each argument. Are you trying to update one _slice_? As you've documented these buttons, you're trying to change whatever your current pie chart is into a single value, which isn't a pie chart (therefore it's not rendering).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! You're right, the code was not reproducible at all. I have edited the code in order to make it more general and added images how it looks like. 
Now I'm rendering a pie with two elements initially. Afterwards, I want to change the colors, values and labels when clicking on ButtonOne or ButtonTwo. 
I've invested multiple hours but did not find any solution.

Comment: I found the solution - i forgot square brackets for all the button argument values (e.g. instead of ' 'labels': ['test1', 'test2'] ' it must be ' 'labels': [['test1', 'test2']] '. Though i don't understand why it must be a list in a list but at least its running now. Additionally, all args must be in one dict: